# Most efficient data type for an input of fixed numbers

Tags: java, enums, custom-data-type

I have some JSON coming to my Java program. It has a particular field with six fixed numbers: 0, 30, 60, 120, 240 or 480. Is it possible in Java to choose a better data type than short? Maybe by using an enum in some form or by representing input in bits by taking advantage of knowing the fixed input in advance?

Regarding enums, they seem to be made for a different use case, from Oracle Java docs for enum, it looks like if I use an enum, it will still end up creating an int internally, so I don't see any advantage ultimately in speed or memory. Is there anything I am missing?

I tried to google but couldn't get an appropriate answer yet.

Comment: Only these numbers are there 0, 30, 60, 120, 240 and 480.? or you can have more numbers than this?

Comment: Unless there is some very specific optimisation required, I'd just use `int` and not worry about it.

Comment: What is your concept of "most efficient"? Memory size? Then use a byte. Programming time? Stick with int. Unless you are transferring millions of those numbers, it won't make much difference anyway.

Comment: @Hardik: Only these six numbers - 0, 30, 60, 120, 240 or 480. May be the sentence wasn't clear, I have edited it now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I would rather consider if you really need to pass these values on your JSON

Comment: @Axel: Thank you for showing interest! I am working on an embedded solution with huge number of these objects(at times, may cross a million), so any optimization would be worth trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, observe that the numbers from your example follow a certain pattern - they are constructed from powers of two multiplied by 30:

- 0 - 0 - `0*30`
- 1 - 2<sup>0</sup> - `1*30`
- 2 - 2<sup>1</sup> - `2*30`
- 4 - 2<sup>2</sup> - `4*30`
- 8 - 2<sup>3</sup> - `8*30`
- 16 - 2<sup>4</sup> - `16*30`

If you store a small number between 0 and 5, inclusive, you can compute the target number back either with a look-up table, or with a simple bit shifting expression:

```
byte b = ... // Store the value in a variable of type "byte"
int num = b!=0 ? 30*(1<<(b-1)): 0;
```

**Note:** Since `enum` is a full-blown class, it would generally use as much or more space than a primitive number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it can't get more efficient than that, hence, accepting the answer.